# fortran & openmp: put multiple do-s and section-s in the same parallel enviroment

Tags: fortran, openmp

I have some serial codes like this:

```
do i=1,N  
    ...  
end do

do j=1,M  
    ...  
end do

...(1)

...(2)
```

Above showed three blocks of serial codes with two do-s and two independent blocks. and I want to adapt it into parallel codes. One way I know of doing is:

```
!$omp parallel do   
do i ...  
!$omp end parallel  

!$omp parallel do  
do j ...  
!$omp end parallel  

!$omp parallel  
!$omp section ...(1)  
!$omp section ...(2)
!$omp end parallel
```

Notice that in doing this way, I am threading four times. As a non-expert, I am not sure if this will cause extra overhead time. Would it be possible to put everything in one parallel environment and would it improve the overhead time?

Thanks!

Comment: Of course it is possible, why didn't you try and measure? We have not enough code to do this.

Comment: I second @VladimirF's comment but I'll go even further with the testiness.  If you ever want to be a programmer you have to acquire the mindset that says *Hmm, I wonder how .. I know, I'll write a little program and figure out what's going on.*  The mindset that thinks *Hmm, I wonder how .. I know, I'll ask a question on Stack Overflow and perhaps a real programmer will tell me* will turn you into a dependent automaton.

Comment: Stop being so condescending.  The question can be answered on the basis of language semantics and knowledge of how an OpenMP runtime library works.  Are you two actually OpenMP experts that are too good to help novice users or are you just trolls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can and probably should amortize the runtime overhead of creating and destroying an OpenMP parallel region by putting all of your parallel constructions - in this case, two do loops and a pair of sections - within a single parallel region.  The following code compiles and executes as expected.

```
program main
implicit none
integer i
!$omp parallel
!$omp do   
do i = 1, 1000
    print*,'loop 1 ',i
enddo
!$omp do   
do i = 1, 1000
    print*,'loop 2 ',i
enddo
!$omp sections
!$omp section
print*,'section 1'
!$omp section
print*,'section 2'
!$omp end sections
!$omp end parallel
return
end program main
```

Note that in this program, the OpenMP thread pool is constructed in the line

```
!omp parallel
```

and not destructed until

```
!omp end parallel
```

You can add "nowait" to reduce the runtime overhead associated with implicit barriers at the end of OpenMP parallel constructs, but only if it preserves the correctness of the code.

Comment: Well, you just showed it is possible to put all in one parallel environment which the OP apparently knew. Whether it will actually help him with the performance of his code remains unknown. It is not true that the OpenMP library has to create a new thread pool on every new parallel directive, it can easily use one thread pool throughout the execution. Of course some overhead remains. Whether it causes a measurable delay in the OP's code cannot be known without actually seeing it and measuring the performance with preferably the same compiler and a similar machine he has.

Comment: OP said "Would it be possible to put everything in one parallel environment and would it improve the overhead time?"  I have enough knowledge of OpenMP parallel region startup and teardown to be sure that this fusion will have a nonnegative performance on all platforms.  Yes, it's true that if the stuff inside of parallel do or sections takes a minute or more, then overhead does not matter, but the fact that the question is being asked indicates that this is not the case.

Comment: An OpenMP parallel region entails at least one OpenMP barrier, which is going to cost thousands of cycles on every platform.  The most efficient implementation of which I am aware is for Blue Gene/Q (http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=6461449), which got the overhead close to 1000 cycles, which is considered miraculous by everyone that has any familiarity with this issue.

Comment: Sure, but you don't know if the OP needs implied barriers on the worksharing constructs anyway or not.

Comment: You can see in Figure 3 of the aforementioned paper on OMP@BGQ that the barrier inside of parallel region construction is less than half of the total time spent here, hence there is an advantage to using "#pragma omp barrier" within a single parallel region instead of creating more than one parallel region.