# OMP SECTIONS and DO in the same PARALLEL block

Tags: multithreading, fortran, openmp

I have 3 tasks which are totally independent from one another and are therefore good candidates for parallel execution:

Task 1: Execute the (single-threaded) subroutine called subA().

Task 2: Execute the (single-threaded) subroutine called subB().

Task 3: Populate an array within a DO loop. Each iteration of the DO-loop is independent of all the others.

Suppose I have 8 threads. I'd like thread 0 to work on Task 1, thread 1 to work on Task 2, and threads 2-7 to work on Task 3. In Fortran, I imagine something like this:

```
COMPLEX*8, EXTERNAL :: func

!$OMP PARALLEL

!$OMP SECTIONS
!$OMP SECTION
  !
  ! Task 1, performed by one thread
  !
  CALL subA()
!$OMP SECTION
  !
  ! Task 2, performed by one thread
  !
  CALL subB()
!$OMP END SECTIONS NOWAIT

!$OMP DO
  !
  ! Task 3, performed by all threads
  !
  DO j=1,nn             
    vals(j) = func(j)
  END DO
!$OMP END DO NOWAIT

!$OMP END PARALLEL
```

But the above code is not quite what I want.  The threads that work on tasks 1 and 2 are also scheduled to work on the DO loop in task 3, which seems to slow everything down, presumably because those 2 threads are "late" arriving at the DO loop and therefore all the other threads must wait for them at the implicit barrier at the end of the PARALLEL region.

What is the proper way to handle the thread scheduling in a case like this?

At the risk of providing too much information, I already know that subA() and subB() are compute-intensive, while each evaluation of func(j) is comparatively fast.  It takes roughly as long for each of subA() and subB() to complete as it does for the entire DO loop to complete when several threads are assigned to the latter task.

Some notes:

1. It is tempting to add the NUM_THREADS(N) clause to "OMP PARALLEL" and NUM_THREADS(N-2) to "OMP DO". But I believe that the "OMP DO" construct does not accept the NUM_THREADS clause.
2. One solution is to use DYNAMIC scheduling on the DO loop. This way, the parallel DO loop will pick up the threads executing subA() and subB() once they are finished. This works, but is unsatisfying because the DYNAMIC scheduling adds a nontrivial amount of overhead, and therefore increases execution time of the DO loop by an unpleasant amount.
3. A related question appears here: [put multiple do-s and section-s in the same parallel environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25576916/fortran-openmp-put-multiple-do-s-and-section-s-in-the-same-parallel-enviromen). However, the answers to that question only establish that it is possible to combine SECTIONS and DO with the same PARALLEL environment, but it does not address the scheduling issue that I raise here.
4. I originally asked this question on Intel's developer forum [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-moderncode-for-parallel-architectures/topic/642089), and it was suggested that I cross-post to stackoverflow.

ETA: Someone from Intel pointed out that my original question was ambiguous: it was not clear whether my DO loop was simply a memcpy() from func(1..nn) to vals(1..nn) or if I was calling a function called func() nn times. The latter was my intent and I clarified this in the example code.

Comment: As I already mentioned on Ryan's original post, adding a schedule clause to the OMP DO seemed too frequently to prevent entering the vectorized branch in my not identical case.  This might be avoided by arbitrarily making it into a nested simd inner parallel outer loop.  This problem might be considered "overhead," but in my case it's not OpenMP overhead, it's the failure to use the simd move instructions, instead hitting the non-optimized remainder loop.  In Ryan's case, there could be automatic memcpy substitution.

Answer (score 0):

Use OpenMP tasks, something like this (untested)

```
!$omp parallel
! Have a single thread create all the tasks. 
!$omp single
!$omp task
   call subA()
!$omp end task
!$omp task
   call subB()
!$omp end task
   DO j=1,nn    
!$omp task         
      vals(j) = func(j)
!$omp end task
   END DO
!$omp end single
!$omp end parallel
```

Comment: I suspect this approach would work nicely if nn were relatively small. But in my case, nn is moderate (hundreds of thousands) and creating hundreds of thousands of OpenMP tasks slows things down quite a bit.

Comment: If you have an OpenMP 4.5 compiler, you can use the taskloop construct to replace the inner loop with its explicit task creation.  Then you can specify a grainsize on the taskloop. Alternately (If you only have an older compiler) you could force it yourself (have an outer loop over chunks to create tasks which then execute an inner loop), and it would still be smaller and more portable than the solution you propose below. (Unless you want to write 288 switch cases when you run on a KNL with 72 coresx4threads, of course :-)).

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I have found so far is to manually perform the scheduling that I hoped OpenMP would automatically perform for me.  In particular, let nthr be the number of threads I wish to use.  Then I use a SELECT CASE construct as follows:

```
SELECT CASE (nthr)
CASE (3)
  ! Use 3 threads. See example below
CASE (4)
  ! Use 4 threads. See example below
CASE (5)
  ! And so on...
CASE DEFAULT
  ! Catch-all
END SELECT
```

In the case where I have 4 threads, I do the following:

```
!$OMP PARALLEL PRIVATE(j) NUM_THREADS(4)
!$OMP SECTIONS
!$OMP SECTION
  !
  ! Task 1, performed by one thread
  !
  CALL subA()

!$OMP SECTION
  !
  ! Task 2, performed by one thread
  !
  CALL subB()

!$OMP SECTION
  !
  ! One thread does half the loop...
  !
  DO j=1,nn/2
    vals(j)=func(j)
  END DO

!$OMP SECTION
  !
  ! ...and one thread does the other half
  !
  DO j=nn/2+1,nn
    vals(j)=func(j)
  END DO

!$OMP END SECTIONS NOWAIT
!$OMP END PARALLEL
```

The cases for the other values of nthr are obvious modifications of the above code.

This solution works nicely in the sense that it is correct and fast, but the code duplication makes it suboptimal from a software engineering point of view.